# SwiftUI Localize Raw Strings

Tags: swift, swiftui

In SwiftUI how can i get my raw string localized?

```swift
Text(#"Hello \\\\"#)
```

Adding this to the localized file will not work.

```swift
"Hello \\\\" = "is not translated \\\\";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Raw strings" don't exist in the syntax of .strings files. See [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/LoadingResources/Strings/Strings.html):

> some characters must be prefixed with a backslash before you can include them in the string. These characters include double quotation marks, the backslash character itself, and special control characters such as linefeed (`\n`) and carriage returns (`\r`).

So when you write:

```
"Hello \\\\" = "is not translated \\\\";
```

You are adding a localised string with the key `Hello \\`. On the other hand, your Swift string is a raw string, which means it represents the string `Hello \\\\`. These are different, so it is not translated.

To fix it, you should change the .strings file to escape each of the backslashes too, as it is a non-raw string:

```
"Hello \\\\\\\\" = "is not translated \\\\\\\\";
```

After that, you still need to convert the Swift raw string to a `LocalizedStringKey` for some reason:

```
Text(.init(#"Hello \\\\"#))
```

Note that the 8 slashes in the .strings file will become 2 slashes when displayed on the screen. This is because the 8 slashes first get reduced to 4 slashes due to the escaping syntax of the .strings file, then, since the `Text.init(_:tableName:bundle:comment:)` initialiser interprets the string as *markdown*, the 4 slashes becomes 2. Backslashes are escaped in markdown too.

Comment: Perfect, wonderful answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here is possible variant

```
Text(verbatim: NSLocalizedString("Hello \\\\", comment: ""))
```

Tested with Xcode 13.3 / iOS 15.4

Answer (score 0):

// ...unless you explicitly convert it to a localized string key.
Text(LocalizedStringKey(yourString))